# kivy: __init__() is missing x required positional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have the class Movie as follows:

```
class Movie(Widget):
    def __init__(self, title, image, time, description, trailer, fsk, threeD, **kwargs):
        super(Movie, self).__init__(title, image, time, description, trailer, fsk, threeD, **kwargs)
        title = StringProperty()
        image = StringProperty()
        time = StringProperty()
        description = StringProperty()
        trailer = StringProperty()
        fsk = NumericProperty()
        threeD = BooleanProperty()
```

When I run my script Python interpreter tells me this:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 7 required positional arguments: 'title', 'image', 'time', 'description', 'trailer', 'fsk', and 'threeD'
```

So what am I doing wrong? I struggle with this some time already.

---

Whole source code relevant to this issue:

```
class Movie(Widget):
    def __init__(self, title, image, time, description, trailer, fsk, threeD, **kwargs):
        super(Movie, self).__init__(title, image, time, description, trailer, fsk, threeD, **kwargs)
        title = StringProperty()
        image = StringProperty()
        time = StringProperty()
        description = StringProperty()
        trailer = StringProperty()
        fsk = NumericProperty()
        threeD = BooleanProperty()

class MainView(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        movies = ListProperty()
        # movies = self.getMovies()
        # for movie in movies:
        #   self.add_widget(movie)

    def getMovies(self, url="http://.../"):
        html = lxml.html.parse(url)
        titles = html.xpath("//h5")
        times = html.xpath("//td[@class='pday ptoday']/span/a")
        trailers = html.xpath("//a[@data-modal-trailer-url]/@data-modal-trailer-url")
        fsks = html.xpath("//tr[@data-fsk]/@data-fsk")
        movies = list()
        # for i in range(0, len(titles)):
        #   movie = Movie(titles[i].text, "images[i]", times[i].text, "", "https:" + trailers[i][:-11], fsks[i], "no")
        #   movies.append(movie)
        return movies
```

Comment: Are you supplying arguments to your `__init__` call? You're probably not. Supply them when initializing the `Movie` class.

Comment: I don't create any objects of type Movie so I don't know why Python interpreter already struggles without knowing what and how many arguments I will pass.

Comment: Well, something is trying to initialize your `Movie` class, what are you running in the interpreter prior to this error?

Comment: @Jim I agree that the executed line that produced the error probably is not included in the question. Have you tried accessing the methods from the class at all? This is also a common error when you do something like: `title = Movie.getTitle()`, i.e., method call without instantiating an instance of the class

Comment: Nope, no method from class Movie is called anywhere. I have those lines commented out. Is this maybe specific to kivy's inheritance?

Comment: What are you doing with the Movie class object? Handing it to some function?

Comment: I've added the whole source code relevant to this issue.

Comment: You say "When I run my script".. but you haven't provided that script, the source you have given never runs anything, just defines a couple of classes..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found out that the kv-lang-file was the reason for this object initialization error. So I don't know how to fix it but I think that is an other question as this is about why `__init__` is being called